# Imprimir un arreglo bidimensional en java

Tags: java, array

Mi duda esta en como puedo imprimir mi arreglo bidimensional  [de esta forma](https://pastebin.com/tst4sxnP)

Mi arreglo es de `8*8` y utilizo esto para imprimir:

```
for (int x=0; x < matriz.length; x++) 
 {
    for (int y=0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) 
    {

     System.out.print(" | ");System.out.print (matriz[x][y]); System.out.print(" | ");

    }
  System.out.println();

 }
```

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo ya formulaste esta pregunta a la cuál @Luiggi  Mendoza dio una respuesta. La forma de imprimir parece ser la  correcta ,ahora todo dependerá de como tenga los datos en su `arrray`

Comment: La pregunta anterior la formulé mal, lo que busco es que imprima esto:https://pastebin.com/tst4sxnP

Comment: por favor, aclara en la pregunta que es lo que tiene que imprimir y como.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Ey, que tal amigo!

```
for (int x=0; x < matriz.length; x++){
        for (int y=0; y < matriz[x].length; y++)
              System.out.print(" | " + matriz[x][y]+ " | ");   
        System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------");

}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.